# Ionic 2 shows me white screen in android 4.2 devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I was just curious on how can I run my Ionic 2 project on Android Jellybean devices well. The application runs well in KitKat to Nougat OS devices but in Jellybean, It only shows white screen. Is there any way I can make my Ionic 2 project be compatible in Android 4.2 (Jellybean) devices? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Crosswalk](https://blog.ionicframework.com/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/)**

> **Why should I use Crosswalk?**
>
> Older versions of Android devices (4.0-4.3) use Android’s default
>   browser, which has significantly less performance and standards
>   compliance than modern Chrome. Using Crosswalk gives you a specific
>   and more performant version of Chrome to use on all Android devices,
>   in order to reduce fluctuations and fragmentation among devices.
>
> **How does Crosswalk improve Cordova Android apps?**
>
> By designating a specific version of Chrome, you can skip the
>   unexpected behavior from browsers that vary from device to device.
>   Crosswalk also provides improved performance and ease of debugging.
>
> **What can I expect, performance and size-wise?**
>
> In older Android Devices (4.0-4.3), you’ll see about a 10x improvement
>   of both HTML/CSS rendering and JavaScript performance and CSS
>   correctness. To bundle Chrome, you will see a small (~10-15MB) size
>   increase in your Android Apps.

More about Crosswalk https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: I would have suggested that but it is no longer maintained https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-final-release.html

Comment: @SurajRao Thanks for the reminder. It's true that Crosswalk is no longer maintained but if any other solution dont work it is worth the try, especially for older versions of Android.